# New ads module function error when clicking to hide ad and to display original content (the video player)

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

I recently added ads box above videos ; I have a problem with the **close ads button** ,it displays **"invalid video id"** error after countdown finish loading and close ad box clicked..

here is the "PlayVideoNow" function ; where i must make the edits to make it load videos correctly?
**Other information:**
CMS : phpmelody 1.6.7
technology: php/smarty

Thanks.any suggestion will be appreciated. 
 To review the hole script :[Get Script from here](http://www.4shared.com/zip/8Ny8Rt3y/php_melody_167.htm)

```
function PlayVideoNow()
    {
        $('#ImgCloseAd').hide();
        $('#video-wrapper').css('background' , 'none');
        $('#video-wrapper').css('padding-top' , '0px');
        $('#BtnPlayNow input[name="closeAd"]').hide();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: MELODYURL2 + "/ajax.php",
                    dataType: "html",
                    data: {
                        "p": "video",
                        "do": "getplayer",
                        "vid": "{/literal}{$preroll_ad_player_uniq_id}{literal}",
                        "aid": "{/literal}{$preroll_ad_data.id}{literal}",
                        "player": "{/literal}{$preroll_ad_player_page}{literal}"
                    },
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#preroll_placeholder').replaceWith(data);
                    }
                });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`{}` field in `.tpl` file will auto parse php variable.

So, in `.tpl` file you don't need to add literal tag.

just try:

```
"vid": "{$preroll_ad_player_uniq_id}",
"aid": "{$preroll_ad_data.id}",
"player": "{$preroll_ad_player_page}"
```

literal tag's usage is to tell smarty not to parse in the `{}` field

```
"{literal}{$preroll_ad_player_uniq_id}{/literal}" 
// equal to "{$preroll_ad_player_uniq_id}" string, not variable
```

Comment: sorry, I have a little misunderstanding. I will modify my answer

Comment: Man i think the literal tags not the problem here..problem is that we re not loading the player and videos codes correctly ,that's why it give an error "invalid video id"?

Comment: I think vid is the abbreviation of video id. When some error like this happened, you can click the right button on the mouse in page and see the source code first(Chrome & Firefox can do this).Check that {$preroll_ad_player_uniq_id} parsed as your expected value.